# Why do i get an error while performing variable assignment using list indexing?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I was studying this code:

```
"""Processes an encoded symbol together with its coefficients."""
def consume_packet(self, coefficients, packet):    
    if not self.is_fully_decoded():
        # add new symbol to decoder matrix and packet vector
        self.coefficient_matrix[self.num_independent][0:self.num_symbols] = coefficients
        self.packet_vector[self.num_independent] = packet
```

To help understand the two lines of code inside the `if` block, I tried this:

```
packet = [1, 2, 4]
num_symbols = 3
coefficient_matrix = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
coefficient_matrix[0][0:num_symbols] = packet # I think this is supposed to extract the packet
print(coefficient_matrix[0])
print(coefficient_matrix[0][0:num_symbols])
```

but I got an error that says `int object does not support item assignment`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: `coefficient_matrix[0]` is just `1`, and you can't do `1[0:num_symbols]`.  I think what you want is `coefficient_matrix[0:num_symbols]`.

Comment: `var[index] = value` assigns, or puts, `value` into some sort of 'slot' in the `var` object.  Actual behavior depends on what `var` is.  This syntax can be used to assign values in a `list`, in a `dict`, or a numpy array (and more).  In your test `coefficient_matrx` is a list, and `coefficient_matrix[0]` is an element of that, in this case a number.  No further indexing is possible.  `coefficient_matrix[0]=23` assigns a new value to the list.  Do you have a introduction to python book?  Read it?

Comment: @hpaulj thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. I wonder what I was thinking in the first place. I am laughing at myself

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally, code like this is expected to be given a Numpy array, rather than a built-in Python list - I notice you tagged the question `numpy` yourself, so I assume you have some awareness of this. At any rate, having multiple `[]` like this implies that the data should have multiple "dimensions", so a simple list won't do. `x[y][z]` means to do `x[y]` first, and then do `[z]` with whatever the result was. It's not clear what is actually confusing about this, but I tried to link some existing questions on the right topic.